# Simple bool switching not working?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am flipping the value of a simple BOOL like this:

```
active = !active;
NSLog(@"%@", active? @"active" : @"not active");
```

I've done this numerous times but right now, for some reason it's not working and it's really pissing me off. When ever the flow hits here, it always prints "active". It's not switching!!

Here's my interface:

```
@interface HeaderView : UIView {
    UILabel *label;
    UIButton *button;
    UIImageView *background;
    BOOL active;
    int section;

    __weak id<HeaderViewDelegate> delegate;
}
```

and function where the action is performed:

```
- (void)actionTUI:(id)sender {
    active = !active;
    NSLog(@"%@", active? @"active" : @"not active");
    UIImage *image = nil;
    if (active) {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"active.png"];
    } else {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unactive.png"];
    }
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [delegate headerView:self toggled:active];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering, is active by default set to YES, because you don't assign it any value, so if you always run it and it is always set to a certain value by default every time you run it, then it will always have the same result. I'm not sure if that is the case though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that after toggling, I was reloading the tableview which apparently recalls:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

which caused a new header view to be allocated/initialized with active set to NO and right after toggling, set to YES. That's why every time, even after flipping the values it was set to active (because right after, it would get discarded and a new header view would come to it's place).

Answer (score 2):

`BOOL`ean values, as with all other types, are initialized to NULL (0, FALSE, NO) at runtime unless assigned a different value.  You are assigning a not(NO) to your BOOL, which prints YES at every run.

Also, your NSLog() is weird, it's probably evaluating itself the wrong way, and most likely contributing to the problem.  It should not include the literal:

```
NSLog(active? @"active" : @"not active");
```

Comment: His `NSLog()` is fine and the first argument should almost always be a compile-time constant expression – usually a literal.